# onclick event in fragment activity not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a activity A in which I have a fragment.

In this activity Fragment changes to fragment A(default when activity A is called) or fragment B based on user input in activity A.

In both fragments A & B I have a button with on click listener. **but this button works only for the first time when activity A is started.**

when user changes fragment the button in those fragments stop responding to on click.

Please suggest what I need to do in order to make buttons in fragment A & B work when fragments are changed by user.

I am replacing fragments based on user input by this code:

```
fr = new FragmentOneDice();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In fragment activity code is like this for on click listener button.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class FragmentOneDice extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Inflate the layout for this fragment


        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_one, container, false);


        button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //MY CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: `this` is not a valid OnClickListener, and the onClick method in the fragment is the onclick of the fragment itself. Try replacing `button1.setOnClickListener(this);` with `button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {/* YOUR CODE */}});`

Comment: why its not valid, can you please explain?. Because as I have said in the question the onClick works when the activity A is created for the first time and user has not tried to change the fragment. onClick stops working when user changes the fragment.

Comment: With all due respect, @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable, FragmentOneDice implements View.OnCLickListener by overriding onClick() and so it's a valid View.OnClickListener.

Comment: Like @Gaurav suggested: please specify your code inside onClick()

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailableI tried what you have suggested , it gives error, onClickListener is abstract, can not be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my activity_main.XML, where I had defined `<Fragment>` as a placeholder for all fragments and had set one fragment as default. So when other fragment was loaded it was getting overlapped resulting in on click event on the button not working, I changed the `<Fragment>` to `<FrameLayout>` as a placeholder. And my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

First You remember one thing,
fragment to fragment direct transaction,or fragment to fragment direct replacement is not possible. it is possible only throw the Activity.

**Define a interface in your first fragment and make container Activity to implement that interface, so you can send your data from Fragment to Activity .In another hand create Second Fragment and define a interface in it. In Content Activity inside implemented methods of First Fragment interface on that define a Second Fragment ,here we assign a data to the second Fragment through interface.**

Comment: I am very new to java and android, i did not understood a thing from your answer. . can you please explain with some example.

Comment: k ,sure. very soon i will post my answer